# Unity GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Player").transform.position;

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hello i have i problem i need to get the transform.position of  more then 1 objects with the tag player so the the script chases multiple  players

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemyChase: MonoBehaviour 
{
    //private GameObject[] Player;
    Transform Player;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Player").transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance (Player.position, this.transform.transform.position) < 10) {
            Vector3 direction = Player.position - this.transform.position;

            this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (this.transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(direction), 0.1f);
            if (direction.magnitude > 1) {

                this.transform.Translate (0,0,0.05f);
            }
        }

    }    
}
```

Comment: Your `Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Player").transform.position;` returns `Array` of `GameObjects`. So you should 1) replace it with `Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").transform.position;` or 2) loop over `Player` array later.

Answer (score 3):

`FindGameObjectsWithTag` [returns an array](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) and arrays don't have a `.transform` property.

You need to use a loop and iterate over the results (possibly to locate the *nearest?*).

Additionally, in your script, `Player` is of Type `Transform` and yet you're attempting to assign the value of `.transform.position` (of Type Vector3) to it.

Comment: so how it must look im a biginner

Comment: @Ghigh I recommend [looking at some documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/using-foreach-with-arrays) or [following some tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wOVu5bQxnbA)

Answer (score 0):

add GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Player")[0].transform.position;